# How can i convert this string to integers & other strings in Python

Tags: python, integer, valueconverter

I got this string...

```
String = '-268 14 7 19  - Fri Aug  3 12:32:08 2018\n'
```

I want to get the first 4 numbers (-268, 14, 7, 19) in integer-variables and Fri Aug 3 12:32:08 in another string-variable.

Is that possible?

Comment: `first, second = String.split(" - ")` ?

Comment: I didn't know about split :/ It's so easy then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using basic python

```
string = '-268 14 7 19  - Fri Aug  3 12:32:08 2018\n'
vals, date = string.strip().split(' - ')
int_vals = [int(v) for v in vals.split()]

print(int_vals)  # [-268, 14, 7, 19]
print(date)  # Fri Aug 3 12:32:08 2018
```

---

Using regex

```
import re
match = re.search(r'([-\d]+) ([-\d]+) ([-\d]+) ([-\d]+)[ -]*(.*)', string)

date = match.group(5)
int_vals = [int(v) for v in match.groups()[:4]]  # same results
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. If i understand this correctly, "split" splits the string into the integers and the timestamp and get rid of the ' - '. Then int_*val* converts the string-values into integer-values and that's it. Looks perfect. If i'd print int_vals(1) do i get -268?

Comment: Yes that's how it works. No you won't get that because this isn't matlab. `print(int_vals[0])` will get you `-268`

Comment: It's funny you found out that I'm mainly using Matlab :P I'll go with print(int_vals[0]). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
String = '-268 14 7 19  - Fri Aug  3 12:32:08 2018\n'
first, second = String.split(" - ")
first = tuple(int(i) for i in first.split())
print(first)
print(second)
```

**Output:**

```
(-268, 14, 7, 19)
Fri Aug  3 12:32:08 2018
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed! I didn't know if you or Mitchell were earlier to post the solution so i gave Mitchell the hook because he had less points :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` and `map` for it:

```
left, date = String.split(' - ')
numbers = list(map(int, left.split()))

print(numbers, date)
```